# Name of question at the end of a quiz to determine a winner

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

On a quiz, where there is a high likelihood of multiple teams scoring the same points, you sometimes add a question that has a numerical answer, e.g. "How many pebbles are there in this jar?".

And if multiple teams have the same quiz score, the team that gets closest to the correct numerical answer on this last question, wins.

Is there a specific name for such a question?

Comment: Tie-breaker seems like a good fit.

Comment: @surlawda After some Googling, I think you're absolutely right. If you enter this as an answer, I would be happy to accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tie-breaker, or [tiebreaker](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiebreaker) seems like a good fit.

> something (such as an extra period of play or an extra question) that is used to decide a winner when a game, contest, etc., has ended with a tied score